# Regular Expression Get Values from String and Divide

Tags: regex

I have below string

```
Actual Number::9000::Total Number::5500
```

Is is possible to take the two numbers using Regular Expressions and get the result of the division of the two numbers to get the percent using Regular Expressions?

Basically, I want to take the string, use regex and my match would be this:

```
Input: Actual Number::9000::Total Number::5500
Output: 61
```

Comment: Grab the numbers? Yes. Calculate whatever? No with regex.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/y87ZFx/1

Comment: Figured as much, thanks for confirming. :(

Comment: Which language are you using here?